# CCM Cassandra create error

Tags: cassandra, ccm

I am getting `HTTP 404` error regardless of C* version I choose. I tried,

`$ ccm create test -v 3.0`

`$ ccm create test -v 2.1`

In both cases I get the error,

```
16:42:23,601 ccm WARNING Downloading 2.1 failed, trying to build from git instead.
The error was: Invalid version 2.1 (underlying error is: HTTP Error 404: Not Found)
http://git.apache.org/cassandra.git git:cassandra-2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running,

`$ ccm create test -v 3.0.0`

`$ ccm create test -v 2.1.0`